# How to use Automapper to map to only properties with prefixes?

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I'm trying to use Automapper to map from Class A to Class B.  However, I want to create a map that ONLY maps when a prefixed field is available on the destination.  How do I do this?

For example, this doesn't work:

```
class TestSource
{
    public long id { get; set; }
}

class TestDest
{
    public long TD_id { get; set; }
    public long id { get; set; }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TestSource lclTS = new TestSource() { id = 20 };

    TestDest lclTD = new TestDest() { id = 30 };

    var lclConfig = new MapperConfiguration
    (
        cfg =>
        {
            cfg.ClearPrefixes();
            cfg.RecognizeDestinationPrefixes("TD_");
            cfg.CreateMap<TestSource, TestDest>();
        }
     );

    IMapper lclMapper = lclConfig.CreateMapper();

    lclMapper.Map(lclTS, lclTD);
}
```

The result will be
lclTS.id = 20
lclTD.id = 20       <<<<<<< Wrong, I didn't map this, there is no prefix, this should stay 30 
lclTD.TD_id = 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto mapper maps the fields which have the same name and type if not explicitly mapped.

Try ForMember method to create explicit mappings between fields.